# Nginx - transparently redirect traffic into another server block

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a NGINX configuration with two virtual hosts (`server {}` blocks): one serving a human-readable site on the primary domain, and the other acting as a reverse-proxy for a specialized service on a subdomain.

```
http {
    <...>

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server my.tld;
        <...>

        location / {
            root /srv/http;
            <...>
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server svc.my.tld;

        <complex reverse-proxy setup with many location blocks>
    }
}
```

For some reason, some clients of the specialized service send their requests to the primary domain (i. e. I see `my.tld/api/endpoint` instead of `svc.my.tld/api/endpoint` in the logs). **I cannot fix these clients. They also don't follow redirects.**

Is there any way to transparently redirect those requests into the correct `server {}` block, without duplicating the whole reverse-proxy configuration in the main server block?

Comment: If it's that clear `/api/endpoint` is the pattern for those clients, then you can add a `location` block in the `my.tld` `server` block to reverse proxy such requests to `svc.my.tld` (and as you wished, not to clone things from within `svc.my.tld` `server` block).

Comment: You can use `include` directive to avoid code duplication.